# Google Forms link to Google Sheets in a specific sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

Here is the situation:

I have a tab 'Page1' that receives data from an application. I need to join these data with data coming from a Google Forms, still in the 'Page1' tab (it needs to be in this tab).

However, when I create the google forms linked to google sheets, it automatically creates another tab and I can't find a way to insert data on the 'Page1' tab.

Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: I think it would be easier to put them both on another sheet using onFormSubmit trigger.

Comment: Join how? There can be multiple ways of joining data. Please explain with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to leave the auto-generated google forms tab alone and let it receive data from the form.

You can pull the data from the form's linked tab to 'Page1' by using the following function:

**=importRange("spreadsheet_url", "range_string")**

In your case, the spreadsheet url would come from your browser. The range string can be pulled by highlighting the cells that you want from the form's tab. An example would be 'A1:D21'.

See the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) for more information on how to use it.